# In MySQL, how to convert this string to a date?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a mysql db with a php frontend.  The data it will use is extracted from another larger db and contains a date/time field which looks like this - 20120301073136 - which records when an event happened.

I understand that this might be a UNIX timestamp?  Not sure.

I want to be show this field in the tables in my PHP webpage as a readable date and time -

ie something like 01-Mar-2012 07:31:36 or similar

Should I try and convert it with SQL command or let PHP format it?  And, what is the code to do so?

BTW, it is important that I can sort the data (in SQL and in the PHP table) into date order - ie in the order that these events happened.

Thanks in advance for your help - Ive learnt a lot here already

J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it to a `datetime` directly in your SQL query. Example:

```
select cast(20120301073136 as datetime)
```

You can also order that with no need to convert it since it is a number in the format  `YYYYMMDDHHmmss`

```
select * from yourTable
order by yourDateTimeField
```

Comment: Thanks.  If I use the command you suggest I replace '20120301...' with the field name, do I?  The field is called A_DT_TM.   Plus - I guess the comment about sorting sounded a little dumb.  I am aware I can sort using order and do that, but I also have some AJAX based sorted of the tables in the php page and I wasnt sure if formating the date with PHP would affect that.

Comment: Yes - replace the `20120301073136` with your field name `A_DT_TM`.

Comment: Thanks this is working for me.  However it shown up another problem in that the MySQL db appears to have stripped the time part from the string.  Ie importing 2.01105E+13 from the csv file source, ends up as something like 20120512000000 in mysql...

Comment: @highfidelity: Looks like your are importing your field with type `float`. Try to change it to `bigint`

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of the MYSQL DATE functions. Check the docs before asking simple questions.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html.

Also you can sort the dates directly in your query using ORDER BY.

Comment: Thanks.  The problem was (still is) that I am not sure what the format of the datestamp I have is - ie is it a UNIX Timestamp or are all 14 digit datestamps the same.

Comment: ...because of that I didnt know what to search for.